# Recursive functions that reverse a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been tasked to create a recursive function that takes in a list and gives the reverse of the list.

I have been able to create the a function named `rev1` which does this:

```hs
rev1 :: [a] -> [a] 
rev1 [] = [] 
rev1 (x:xs) = reverse xs ++ [x]
```

But I have been asked to create a another function 'rev2' which should use an additional argument serving as an accumulator.

Could somebody please help me compose the `rev2` function.

Thanks in advance, 
Sam

Comment: Your `rev1` isn't recursive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your `rev1` should be this instead:

```hs
rev1 :: [a] -> [a] 
rev1    []  = [] 
rev1 (x:xs) = rev1 xs ++ [x]
```

The point of `rev2` would be to achieve tail recursion by means of passing the intermediate result inside an accumulator argument:

```hs
rev2 :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
-- if applied to an empty list, just return the result
-- so far, i.e. whatever is inside the accumulator:
rev2 acc    []  =         acc
-- otherwise, take the head of the list and append it to
-- the accumulator, and carry on with the rest of the list
rev2 acc (x:xs) = rev2 (x:acc) xs
```

this, however, obviously has the downside of exposing the `acc` argument to users of `rev2`, so a typical approach is hiding the accumulator based implementation behind a façade that looks exactly like `rev1`:

```hs
rev2 :: [a] -> [a]
rev2 xs = go [] xs where
  go :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]  -- signature included for clarity
  go acc    []  =       acc
  go acc (x:xs) = go (x:acc) xs
```

Comment: It's not about tail recursion. It's about avoiding the numerous expensive applications of `++`.

Comment: I might also mention that `go` might better be named `revOnto`, since it reverses a list onto the front of another list.

Comment: I guess it's both about tail rec. as well as your point, then?

Comment: An alternative expression: `reverse xs = foldr (\x r acc -> r (x : acc)) id xs []`. This is clearly not tail recursive, but it is reasonable.

Comment: Right, it should be memory-optimal. Constructor application is never suspended, so `x : acc` should be constructed before forcing `r`. In reality, GHC has machinery that optimizes that very well. `reverse` is not defined that way because it turns out that letting `reverse` participate in fold/build fusion is sometimes bad.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start things off:

```
rev2 :: [a] -> [a]
rev2 xs = rev2' xs ???

rev2' :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
rev2' [] ys = ???
rev2' (x : xs) ys = ???
```